# Question on python Webscraper with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping

So my goal with this personal project would be creating a word list and the frequency of those words on a webpage. I found a nifty guide here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-crawl-web-page-get-frequent-words/ but this guide seemingly only works for the website they provided. I would like to have my word list program actually be able to scrape words from real websites. I ran into a HTTP Error 403 for a while but found a way to get around that. What must I change now to actually scrape other websites than this one?? My feeling is it has to do with either the BSOBJ soups findAll or something else. I got passed the other part but I am kinda stuck now

Here is my python3 code.

```
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import operator
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

def get_words(target):
    wordsl = []
    req = Request(target,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    source = urlopen(req).read() #requests.get(target).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')

    for text in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'entry-content'}):
        content = text.text
        words = content.lower().split()

        for word in words:
            wordsl.append(word)
        clean_list(wordsl)

def clean_list(wordlist):
    clean = []
    bad = '!@#$%^&*()_-=+{}[]\|"<>,.:;?/ '

    for word in wordlist:
        for i in range(0,len(bad)):
            word=word.replace(bad[i],'')

        if len(word) > 0:
            clean.append(word)

    add_count(clean)

def add_count(final_words):
    word_count = {}

    for word in final_words:
        if word in word_count:
            word_count[word] += 1

        else:
            word_count[word] = 1

    output(word_count)

def output(words):
    #words = sorted(words.values())
    for x in words:
        print(x,':',words[x])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_words(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: That script will only find words inside `div` tags with the class `entry-content`. Most sites won't have any such tags. I just glanced at your link and it does indeed say as much. In general there is no "magic formula" for scraping data from an arbitrary web page, it all depends how that page is structured.

Comment: If you're wondering, I'm referring to this comment in the original source: `# Text in given web-page is stored under  # the <div> tags with class <entry-content> `. By "the given web-page" they mean the specific one they're scraping - NOT arbitrary websites.

Comment: Hello @icoder -- In case you have found my answer helpful to your problem, please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
for text in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'entry-content'}):
```

determines in which HTML elements the program looks for words.

Specifically, from the parsed HTML tree stored in the `soup` object, only the `div` elements that have a `class` of `entry-content` are considered. This is specific to the [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-crawl-web-page-get-frequent-words/) website that hosts the guide, which includes HTML source like:

```
<div class="entry-content">
        <p>The task is to count the most frequent words...
```

But other websites are not going to necessarily use a class `entry-content` at all. So no element is going to match your `soup.findAll` call.

One assumption that can be made, that may work in many websites, is that text can be found inside `<p>` (paragraph) tags.

So you can change the `soup.findAll` line to something like this:

```
for text in soup.findAll('p'):
```

This way, all text under any `<p>` tag in the webpage will be considered for the word frequency counting.

I tried the above on two pages of well-known sites:

- A [Reddit comment thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/news/comments/am47ov/a_fedex_worker_found_dead_at_a_delivery_facility/).
- A [New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/02/01/us/politics/cory-booker-2020.html).

And it seems to output word frequencies.

You can try more sites. If you are not want to "debug" why you can't get any words in a particular website, visit that website in your browser, and use "View page source" (in the right-click menu) and then Ctrl+F, to find the kind of HTML tags that contain text on that website.